# Install Outlook Extension in Thin Client OWA application

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server, outlook-2010, outlook-web-app

I have developed an extension for Outlook and currently have it installed on a thick client Outlook instance. I would like to enable the same extension for the thin client OWA application but can't find any documentation about developing OWA extensions.

Is it possible to simply port an Outlook extension to a thin client version that can be installed on OWA? Or is this something that will need to be redeveloped from scratch?

My extension was built for Outlook Exchange 2010 in C#.

Thanks!